# Modal with svg contentnot aligning properly vertically first time

Tags: html, svg, modal-dialog

I use sematic-ui css framework and load a modal with svg content.
The modal loads the first time after a page refresh half way the screen.
After clicking the modal link it a second time without a page refresh, the modal is on its correct place.
This happens with all the modals on the page.
When i display a png in the modal, with the same html and css, it behaves as expected, it is placed in the correct place.

Code of the modal an the javascript calling it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ui.button.modal1456524726671605').click(function () {
    $('.ui.modal.modal1456524726671605').modal('show')
});
});
</script>



    <div class="ui small modal modal1456524726671605"><i class="icon  close"></i>
  <div class="header ui">Window title</div>
  <div class="content">
    <figure>
      <embed src="../static/img/charts/1456524726671605hnxiwhkc.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%"/>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could not find out what is causing this behaviour, so maybe one of you have a clue for me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bootstrap is known to have a few issues, for example, on "modal show" the body tag will have additional classes that will modify its overflow behavior and other stuff. Check what changes are made to your css when you  launch the modal

Comment: Please note that this is not bootstrap, i use semantic-ui.

Comment: Could still have the same issue